# Количество решений диофантова уравнения на заданном промежутке

Tags: математика

Необходимо посчитать кол-во решений уравнения вида a*x+b*y+c*z=d.
Для трех коэффициентов всё понятно. А для четырех - нет.
http://e-maxx.ru/algo/diofant_2_equation

Не очень хочу углубляться в дискретную математику, так что может кто внятно объяснит как найти кол-во решений такого уравнения?

Answer (score 1):

Фиксировать одну из переменных на всех значениях в диапазоне и решать диофантово уравнение для двух оставшихся.

Это уравнение плоскости, пересекающей параллелепипед допустимых значений. Фактически мы фиксируем один уровень (например, z=3) и находим число целых точек на отрезке, являющемся пересечением исходной плоскости, плоскости z=3, вертикальных плоскостей диапазонов x=xmin, x=xmax, y=ymin, y=ymax

На всякий случай - производящая функция для данного уравнения при целых неотрицательных коэффициентах

```
P(t) = 1 / ((1 - t^a)*(1 - t^b)*(1 - t^c))
```

Если её разложить в ряд, то коэффициент при d-м члене даст число целых неотрицательных решений.

Пример для уравнения

```
2x + y + 3*z = 7
series(1/((1-t)*(1-t^2)*(1-t^3)), t=0, 8);

              2      3      4      5      6      7      8
   1 + t + 2 t  + 3 t  + 4 t  + 5 t  + 7 t  + 8 t  + O(t )
```

Количество решений 8

Можно ли это доработать для ограниченного промежутка - не скажу.